# Singular value decomposition problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ have singular values $\sigma_{1}\ge\sigma_{2}\ge\cdots\ge\sigma_{k}$ (where $k=\min\{m,n\}$).Assume $\sigma_{r}>0$, $\sigma_{r+1}=0$. Prove that $\operatorname{rank}(A)=r$. I know it is from URV. But I do not know how to solve this problem directly.

Comment: Could you remind the audience what URV is...?

Comment: Yeah,but the in $URV$, there is an equation that I do not know why,$rank(U^{T}AV)=rank(A)=r$.

Comment: Can you show that $\operatorname{rk} R = r$? This is the 'difficult' part.

Comment: $r_{ij}=u^{T}_{i}Av_{j}$,$u_{i}^{T}=0$ for $i=r+1,\ldots,m$and$Av_{j}=0$for $j=r+1,\ldots,n$

Comment: I was thinking in terms of the dyadic expansion $A= \sum_i \sigma_i u_i v_i^*$. Then $Av_i = \sigma_i u_i$, hence $\{A v_i\}_{i=1}^r$ are linearly independent, hence $\operatorname{rk} A \ge r$. Furthermore, $A v_i = 0$ for $i=r+1,...,m$, hence $\dim \ker A \ge m-r$. The rank nullity theorem gives the desired result.

Comment: @copper.hat You could post that as an answer...

Comment: @40votes: Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the dyadic expansion $A= \sum_i \sigma_i u_i v_i^*$. Then $Av_i = \sigma_i u_i$, hence $\{A v_i\}_{i=1}^r$ are linearly independent, hence $\operatorname{rk} A \ge r$. Furthermore, $Av_i=0$ for $i=r+1,...,m$, hence $\dim \ker A \ge m-r$. The rank nullity theorem gives the desired result.